# Hybris: Localization on CSCockpit

Tags: localization, sap-commerce-cloud, cs-cockpit

I have added a new column in the Order Search result by customizing the "Order_OrderSearchResult_CockpitGroup.xml" and adding its entry in "projectdata_cscockpit_ui_components.impex". I added the property value in both English and Japanese locale property files.

I ran the impex file again in HAC, then did a hybris update by selecting cscockpit and after that reset the user setting in cockpit menu. But I'm only able to see the English locale property and not the Japanese locale property while logging through Japanese locale.

Am I missing something?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried by adding the same Japanese property to both i3-label_en.properties and i3-label_ja.properties file by using normal characters as well as unicode but it was not reflecting even after hybris update and resetting personal settings in cockpit.

I resolved this issue by adding the Japanese property in unicode in the customized cockpit locales_en.properties and locales_ja.properties file. Since our website is not using English characters, so I had to add same Japanese property in both files. Not the best way, but yes this workaround worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the label in i3-label_{lang code}.properties file?

Comment: Yes. I have added that file for Japanese locale. I also tried using both the exact Japanese characters as well as its Unicode characters. But still, its not getting reflected. It only shows the English locale property.

Comment: is that the problem is only for the above file or you are not able to see Japanese characters in the complete cockpit?

Comment: I'm able to see Japanese characters for other fields in the cockpit. This new field I added through customization in CS Cockpit. So, I think I'm missing something that its not getting proper hybris update though HAC. But the English characters of new field is seen and not the Japanese one, is pretty strange.